Scaffold-DbContext, is it possible to skip modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema in the generated code?
We generated Data (for DBContext) and Models by scaffolding an existing SQL Server database. In the result, we found the following checking of modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(). For scaffolding, we connected to the database through integrated security as Trusted_Connection=True;, so we believe the generated source code therefore checks whether the user's schema still exists by default.
     ...
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("DOMAIN\\user.name");
         ...

We wonder whether it is possible to let the Scaffold-DbContext command skip this checking in the generated source code.
We have tried manually removing the statement modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("DOMAIN\\user.name");, and the program works OK, so this checking is not absolutely necessary in our case.

You can only remove it if you always login with a user who's default schema is "DOMAIN\user.name". In other words, remove it and EF will try to find its mapped tables in the logged-in user's default schema (they won't be prefixed by the schema in the generated SQL.)
